# Memory allocation issue in writing Spark DataFrame to Hive table

Tags: python, apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to save a Spark DataFrame to a Hive table (Parquet) with `.saveAsTable()` in pySpark, but keep running in to memory issues like below:

```
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: parquet.hadoop.MemoryManager$1:
New Memory allocation 1034931 bytes is smaller than the minimum allocation size of 1048576 bytes.
```

The first number (`1034931`) generally keeps changing in different runs. I recognize the second number (`1048576`) is `1024^2`, but I have little idea what that means here.

I have been using the exact same technique for a few other of my projects (with much larger DataFrames), and it has worked without issue. Here I have essentially copy-pasted the structure of the process and configuration but runs in to the memory problem! It must be something trivial I am missing.

The Spark DataFrame (let's call it `sdf`) has the structure (~10 columns and ~300k rows, but could be more if this runs correctly):

```
+----------+----------+----------+---------------+---------------+
| col_a_str| col_b_num| col_c_num|partition_d_str|partition_e_str|
+----------+----------+----------+---------------+---------------+
|val_a1_str|val_b1_num|val_c1_num|     val_d1_str|     val_e1_str|
|val_a2_str|val_b2_num|val_c2_num|     val_d2_str|     val_e2_str|
|       ...|       ...|       ...|            ...|            ...|
+----------+----------+----------+---------------+---------------+
```

The Hive table was created like this:

```
sqlContext.sql("""
                    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_hive_table (
                        col_a_str string,
                        col_b_num double,
                        col_c_num double
                    ) 
                    PARTITIONED BY (partition_d_str string,
                                    partition_e_str string)
                    STORED AS PARQUETFILE
               """)
```

The attempt at inserting data to this table is with the following command:

```
sdf.write \
   .mode('append') \
   .partitionBy('partition_d_str', 'partition_e_str') \
   .saveAsTable('my_hive_table')
```

The Spark/Hive configuration is like this:

```
spark_conf = pyspark.SparkConf()
spark_conf.setAppName('my_project')

spark_conf.set('spark.executor.memory', '16g')
spark_conf.set('spark.python.worker.memory', '8g')
spark_conf.set('spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead', '15000')
spark_conf.set('spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors', '64')
spark_conf.set('spark.executor.cores', '4')

sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=spark_conf)

sqlContext = pyspark.sql.HiveContext(sc)
sqlContext.setConf('hive.exec.dynamic.partition', 'true')
sqlContext.setConf('hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions', '5000')
sqlContext.setConf('hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode', 'nonstrict')
sqlContext.setConf('hive.exec.compress.output', 'true')
```

I have tried changing the `.partitionBy('partition_d_str', 'partition_e_str')` to `.partitionBy(['partition_d_str', 'partition_e_str'])`, increasing memory, splitting the DataFrame to smaller chunks, re-creating the tables and DataFrame, but nothing seems to work. I can't find any solutions online either. What would be causing the memory error (I don't fully understand where it's coming from either), and how can I change my code to write to the Hive table? Thanks.

Comment: The minimum page size i.e. minimum read /write unit of parquet is defined by property `parquet.page.size` which defaults to 1048576. Its possible that data your are trying to write falls under this threshold. Thats why is throwing error may be? this is just my speculation... [check this out](https://github.com/Parquet/parquet-mr/blob/fa8957d7939b59e8d391fa17000b34e865de015d/parquet-hadoop/src/main/java/parquet/hadoop/ParquetOutputFormat.java#L64)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Tried your suggestion by playing with the `parquet.page.size` and `parquet.block.size` configurations, as well as by just multiplying the size of my data, but no luck. Same error :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out I was partitioning with a nullable field that was throwing the `.saveAsTable()` off. When I was converting the RDD to a Spark DataFrame, the schema I was providing was generated like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

# Define schema
my_schema = StructType(
                    [StructField('col_a_str', StringType(), False),
                     StructField('col_b_num', DoubleType(), True),
                     StructField('col_c_num', DoubleType(), True),
                     StructField('partition_d_str', StringType(), False),
                     StructField('partition_e_str', StringType(), True)])

# Convert RDD to Spark DataFrame
sdf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(my_rdd, schema=my_schema)
```

Since `partition_e_str` was declared as `nullable=True` (the third argument for that `StructField`), it had issues when writing to the Hive table because it was being used as one of the partitioning fields. I changed it to:

```
# Define schema
my_schema = StructType(
                    [StructField('col_a_str', StringType(), False),
                     StructField('col_b_num', DoubleType(), True),
                     StructField('col_c_num', DoubleType(), True),
                     StructField('partition_d_str', StringType(), False),
                     StructField('partition_e_str', StringType(), False)])
```

and all was well again!

Lesson: Make sure your partitioning fields are not nullable!